# When using RealityView, why does it work in preview, but not in the Vision Pro simulator?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit, visionos

This is my app code, trivial:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct LogicVisionApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }.windowStyle(.volumetric)
    }
}
```

This is my ContentView code:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        // Register components
        DraggableComponent.registerComponent()
        [snip...]
        
        // Register systems
        TransmittableStaticInitSystem.registerSystem()
        [snip...]
        
        NSLog("I am running?!")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            // Add test entities
            let testWire = try! Entity.load(
                    named: "Wire",
                    in: realityKitContentBundle)
            content.add(testWire)

            [snip...]

            NSLog("I am running 2?!")
        }
        .gesture(DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
            .targetedToEntity(
                where: QueryPredicate<Entity>.has(DraggableComponent.self))
            .onChanged { value in
                value.entity.position = value.convert(
                    value.location3D,
                    from: .global,
                    to: value.entity.parent!)
            }
        )
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

- It works as expected in Preview (except for the logs not showing up).
- When the app launches in Simulator, nothing appears in the volumetric window.

  - It prints:

    - "I am running?!"
    - "I am running 2?!"
    - (A log stating that the system update is running as expected)
    - (A log stating that the system update found an entity with the proper components for 1 frame, but that log doesn't appear on any other frame [maybe they despawned?])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the volumetric window is clipping your content. Try adding the `.fixedSize()` modifier to the `RealityView`.

Alternatively you can add a `.defaultSize(width: height: depth: in:)` to the Volumetric WindowGroup in [order to scale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/positioning-and-sizing-windows/#Specify-a-volume-size) it to the appropriate size to fit the RealityView's content. ie.

`.defaultSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0, depth: 2.0, in: .meters)`

You should be able to get logs from preview content, in Xcode next at the bottom of the log window is a "Previews" toggle which should give you logs from the preview.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works! You have a typo: "you ~~can~~ should". I would like to add that unfortunately the preview log still [doesn't seem to be working for me](https://i.imgur.com/kzUFpCY.png), but it's not a concern for now.

Comment: try `print()` rather than `NSLog()` for preview logs